# Imagem só aparece na web se atualizar projeto no Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Boa noite,

Estou rodando um projeto no IDE Eclipse, servidor TomCat e utilizando o Primefaces.
Em uma tabela em que eu tenho imagens, as mesmas só aparecem quando eu "dou um refresh" no projeto dentro do Eclipse, como se após a inserção da imagem, ele apenas enxergasse se eu forçá-lo a isto.

Já passaram por algo parecido ou tem alguma solução?

Comment: Você as adiciona por fora do Eclipse?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Faço via upload do PrimeFaces, salvo o path no banco.